# How do you create a waterfall elevator?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

In Minecraft Alpha Single Player Survival, what are the specifications to create a waterfall elevator to go from the bottom of a long mine shaft to the surface?

Comment: Water elevators have been brok--- fixed by Notch in 1.6

Comment: @badp in [1.6.6](http://notch.tumblr.com/post/6035819427/minecraft-beta-1-6-6) they have been put back in.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

If I understand the theory, here's how you do it.

```
≋≋≋≋≋█ ← remove this           - ground level
██████   when ready
     █   
     █   
     █  
 ................................................... 
     █   
     █   
     █   
     █       █                 - mine level
      ███████
```

Remove the marked block and this happens:

```
≋≋≋≋≋≋~                        - ground level
██████≋              
     █≋  
     █≋  
     █≋ 
 ................................................... 
     █≋  
     █≋  
     █≋  
     █≋~~~~~~█                 - mine level
      ███████
```

To move up and down, swim up and down the column of water; move slightly out to breathe then continue your ascension.

---

A boat makes this faster as [Strix explains](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/8853/how-do-you-create-a-waterfall-elevator/8854#8854) and [this video demostrates](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3o0U0G8WOXc). However, you must allow further space down to avoid crashing on the bottom:

```
 ................................................... 
     █≋  
     █≋  
     █≋  
     █≋≋≋≋≋≋≋█                 - mine level
     █≋≋≋≋≋≋█
     █≋≋≋≋≋█                   - extra space to break the fall
      █████
```

[This video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lOze0uBbxNA&NR=1) shows, however, that you can also climb a boat elevator by simply swimming.

Comment: To make the extra space you'll need [this technique](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/10597/how-do-i-flood-a-mine/10681#10681)

Comment: Boats are no longer useable in water elevators since 1.6.

Comment: Video is down, too.

Comment: @Konerak The video plays okay to me... perhaps a song-related background music?

Answer (score 9):

Boats float in water.  Essentially, all you need is a waterfall from ground level straight down from the top of your mine shaft to the bottom.  Then, while at the bottom, boat your way into the waterfall and watch as you rocket to the top.

Comment: You can also hold space when not in a boat, but it's MUCH slower.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a better design.

First, make a hole that is 3x3 wide and as deep as you want.
At the bottom, add a block to the center, then dig out the sides:

```
2 2 1 2 2
2 0 0 0 2
1 0 2 0 1
2 0 0 0 2
2 2 1 2 2
```

The 1's except the center are possible exits. The numbers represent the number of blocks from the ground.

At the top, you have your hole:

```
X X X X X
X 0 0 0 X
X 0 0 0 X
X 0 0 0 X
X X X X X
```

Above it, place a wood balcony, at least 1 block between it and the pit:

```
X X W X X
X W W W X
X 0 0 0 X
X 0 0 0 X
X X X X X
```

then, place water on top of it (water will be B, W is wood)

```
X X W X X
X W B W X
X 0 0 0 X
X 0 0 0 X
X X X X X
```

It will flow down and make a perfect place to create a water elevator.

In order to use it, make a boat, place it on the middle block (at the bottom) and get into it(quickly).

To go down, just freefal but catch yourself in the water pillar near the end.

Note: the boat breaks each time when you do it this way, but boats are cheap, and it's easier to use.