# Artificial Lake Minecraft

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Is there any way to create an artificial lake in minecraft? I am familiar with the system of "spring" water blocks and how to create an infinite supply of water with two blocks together, but how do you make an entire lake?

Comment: Possible Duplicate: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/10597/how-do-i-flood-a-mine

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Basically, you want to start by digging out the top layer of your soon-to-be-lake. Place water sources every other block (in a checkerboard like fashion), and you will hopefully end up with a non-flowing lake. The reason this happens is because by placing water sources every other block, they flow together and the one in between also turns into a source.

If you still have flowing water, place water where the water seems to be flowing to:

[image]

From there, you should be able to dig the bottom layers of the lake out without any annoying currents forming. If they do, follow the instructions in [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/10318/how-can-i-level-water).

Comment: I'll give this a shot with a test lake and flag it as the answer if it works. Does the bottom have to be level?

Comment: It's easiest to level water when there's only one layer of water. If you then dig out the bottom layers, they should all work fine.

Comment: @Kort there is no requirement on the lower layers whatsoever. however the lower layers will (by digging) be "waterfall" blocks pulling you down. If you want really still water, follow [these instructions](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/10597/how-do-i-flood-a-mine/10681#10681) (that's why @Ullallulloo considers your question a dupe of that one)

Comment: Yes, those blocks will become flowing blocks (flowing down) and not source blocks (the kinds that can be easily swam in). I suppose you could repeat the block-placing process on each layer down. It depends on whether you're making the lake for looks or actually for function; if it's just for looks then you don't need to bother making the lower level sources.

Comment: Actually, you will be able to swim in the lower layers. The condition for a downward current is *NOT* that the block is not a source block, but that the block has open space beside it. (Yes, I tested this.)

Comment: This is true, and infact a pool made with just the top layer (which is also mentioned in accepted answer to the duplicated question) can be used as a plunge pool without ill effect. In previous versions there was a very definite downward current in pools made this way. Recently the same effect only sometimes occurs, but is probably a bug more than by design.