# How can I make a boatlock in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

How can I navigate a boat to a higher level in Minecraft?

Is there some form of a lock that I could use?

Maybe something using doors and watersource...

Inspired by this question: [Is it possible to build a new river across a land barrier?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/12744)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you create a waterfall elevator?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/8853/how-do-you-create-a-waterfall-elevator)

Comment: I don't think this qualifies as a duplicate question. The answer is the same, yes, but that closing it for that reason is like closing "what is 2 + 2?" as a duplicate of "What is 1 + 3?".

Comment: If you don't mind modding, the [finite liquid](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/259303-152-finiteliquid-v593/) mod might allow you to construct a real water lock with pistons (or doors?)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

**Current as of Retail 1.1**

Okay so the key mechanic that broke the traditional waterfall elevator was that boats no longer travel upward in a waterfall. However, **boats will move rapidly upward in source blocks**.

So what is a source block? A source block (also known as "still water") is water that is created during map creation or placed with a bucket. Water that "flows" from this block is informally known as moving water. So in order to create a modern boat elevator, we need to create a shaft of only source blocks.

Here is my construction.

1:  I created a canal with a glass wall and an "entranceway" fitted with signs. These signs prevent water from flowing past them but still allow boats through.

[image]

2: I build up a second layer of glass walls around my new shaft. Then I flood this layer with water. Note that I have to fill each of the four blocks in this layer of the shaft with water from the bucket - these are now all source blocks. Notice how none of them are moving. If the water is moving, you need to add more hits from your bucket.

[image]

3: I keep adding glass layers and each time I do, I add a layer of source water.

[image]

4: Here I've added a spillway at the top where the boat can float after it has risen up the shaft.

[image]

You can download this world here:

http://reactor.tophatandmonocle.com/boatlift.zip

Comment: There is much win in this post.

Answer (score 15):

#### This applies to versions before Beta 1.6.4

All you have to do is set up a waterfall. Boats, contrary to what one would expect, simply flow straight up waterfalls.

Alternatively, water cannot pass through doors. You can rig something with that if you're patient.

Comment: Water won't pass through doors, open or closed.  So your lock system would end up being more of a dam.

Comment: @GnomeSlice - "water cannot pass through doors". How does that disagree with your comment?

Comment: @Raven > I'm just not sure how you were planning to rig up a lock system using doors.  :P

Comment: @Gnomeslice - you can easily get your boat's momentum high enough that you can travel through the air block without stopping. Same idea where you can put a switch (or other non-minecart track block) in the path of your minecart and still have it complete its circuit.

Comment: @Raven > I hadn't thought of that, but won't a speed like that cause you to smash into the other side of your lock, unless you dig it out a long way?

Comment: @GnomeSlice - honestly, I  was only speaking from a "getting out" perspective. I haven't tried re-docking, as it were.

Comment: @Raven > Aha!  It doesn't matter how many other problems you create, as long as you solve the initial one!  I like your style.